# FileSystemWatcher - Reading last line of file after update?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to write a simple console application that waits for a change to a file then reads just the last line of that file. The file watcher works and the change event fires.  But I'm struggling to work out how read from the file.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Path = "E:\\myFilePath";
            watcher.Filter = "";
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines(e.FullPath).Last());
        }
```

when testing (editing the file in notepad) it will work once, then after a second edit I get the error...

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file '' because
>   it is being used by another process.'

Comment: ReadLines may not be closing the file in time. Have  you tried a `StreamReader` variant which you can explicitly close after usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Note that the `Changed` event will be raised twice for the same file. Cache the last file name and don't do anything if it's the same file you're already parsing.

Comment: @AvinKavish  ``using (StreamReader sr = ...`` doesn't want to work at all for me. :(

Comment: The event fires when the "LastWritten" timestamp of the file changes. This does not mean that the writing application closed the file. If the file is not closed, you won't be able to read it.
The exact strategy depends on the program writing the file.
In the simplest case, a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` may suffice

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to an already open handle to the file. `File.ReadLines` uses an iterator internally which is Disposable. Use this to ensure Disposal during the lifetime of your event handler.

```
        static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(e.FullPath);
            Console.WriteLine(lines.Last());
            lines.GetEnumerator().Dispose();
        }
```

This should guarantee disposal before the end of event handler.

Edit: In the case that a different process is holding a write lock to the file, use `Thread.Sleep(ms)` with a safe time as inspecting and releasing file handles is not feasible in C#.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me.  Same results, works first time, errors on second file update.

Answer (score 1):

I still ran into problems using lines.GetEnumerator().Dispose();

You can add a pause before opening the file, just chose your poison for doing so.

```
    static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 500000; x++)
        {
            int t = x;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines(e.FullPath).Last());
    }
```

I tried using SreamReader too but still ran into the same problem.

```
        // Does not work
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
        {
            while (r.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                m = r.ReadLine();
            }
            r.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n", m);
```